# how to give proper permission for pcntl_exec?

Tags: php, process

I am trying to fork a php script and execute another php script using pcntl_exec command, but I am getting following error:

`pcntl_exec(): Error has occured: (errno 13) Permission denied`

I am trying following code after normal forking in a function:

```
    $pathToFile="/var/www/html";
    $outputfile =array("mytestfile.php");
    if ($pid) // parent
    {
          $pid_arr[$i] = $pid;
    }
    else // child
    { 
           pcntl_exec($cmd,$outputfile);
           return "error occurred in child";
    }
```

All other pcntl functions are working properly, I tried chmod and chown commands on my directory as well, but still pcntl_exec is not working.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Seems like a permission issue,can i know exactly which environment you are using?? (OS)?

Comment: I am using lamp on ubuntu..

Answer (score 1):

Try this option:

```
chmod 755 /var/www/html
```

this should grant you the permission needed!